# I am exporting CSS value variables, why aren't they being applied?

Tags: css, create-react-app, css-variables, react-typescript, react-css-modules

I'm using create-react-app with TypeScript template and trying to implement color variables as follows in a styles/colors.css file:

```
@value MainBlue: #255EDF;
@value MainOrange: #FF6F4A;
@value MainYellow: #FFD640;
```

When I go to import them (see below) in a CSS module they are not implementing.

```
@value MainYellow from '~styles/colors.css';

.homePage {
  background-color: MainYellow;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```
import styles from './homePage.module.css';

const HomePage = () => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.homePage}>Home</div>
    );
};

export default HomePage;
```

What am I missing in order for these to be applied?

Answer (score 0):

This syntax will do the job!

```css
:root {
  --MainBlue: #255EDF;
  --MainOrange: #FF6F4A;
  --MainYellow: #FFD640;
}
.homePage {
  background-color: var(--MainYellow);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="homePage">Home</div>
```

Comment: For some reason this doesn't seem to work either.  Just to clarify, are you saying that ```:root {
  --MainBlue: #255EDF;
  --MainOrange: #FF6F4A;
  --MainYellow: #FFD640;
}
.homePage {
  background-color: var(--MainYellow);
  text-align: center;
}``` 
should all be in one file?